# LLVM IR - from IR Assembly Format to C

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I know you can you llvm-dis to get Assembly Format (*.ll) from IR. Is there a way to get C from Assembly Format? Actually to translate certain parts of it to C?

I.e this code:

test.c

```
#define NMAX    9 
#include <stdio.h>
typedef short Word16;

Word16 gmed_n(            /* o : the median value    */
        Word16 ind[],   /* i : input values        */
        Word16 n        /* i : number of inputs    */
         )
{
    Word16 i, j, ix = 0;
    Word16 max;
    Word16 medianIndex;
    Word16  tmp[NMAX];
    Word16  tmp2[NMAX];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(tmp2 + i) = *(ind + i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        max = -32767;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (*(tmp2 + j) >= max)
            {
                max = *(tmp2 + j);
                ix = j;
            }
        }
        *(tmp2 + ix) = -32768;
        *(tmp + i) = ix;
    }


    medianIndex = *(tmp + (n >> 1));  /* account for complex addressing */

    return (*(ind + medianIndex));
}

int main()
{
    short a[5]={1,32767,3,4,5};
    int i = 0;
    short res;
    res=gmed_n(a,5);
    printf("%i\n",res);
}
```

How can I translate  (part from LL)

```
85:                                               ; preds = %34
  %86 = getelementptr inbounds [9 x i16], [9 x i16]* %10, i64 0, i64 0
  %87 = load i16, i16* %4, align 2
  %88 = sext i16 %87 to i32
  %89 = ashr i32 %88, 1
  %90 = sext i32 %89 to i64
  %91 = getelementptr inbounds i16, i16* %86, i64 %90
  %92 = load i16, i16* %91, align 2
  store i16 %92, i16* %9, align 2
  %93 = load i16*, i16** %3, align 8
  %94 = load i16, i16* %9, align 2
  %95 = sext i16 %94 to i32
  %96 = sext i32 %95 to i64
  %97 = getelementptr inbounds i16, i16* %93, i64 %96
  %98 = load i16, i16* %97, align 2
  ret i16 %98
```

To C:

```
return (*(ind + medianIndex));
```

How would you approach it? What tech stack?

I would like to pinpoint C code from LLVM IR Assembly format.

Comment: For non-trivial cases with optimisation, no.

Comment: What you can do under the debugger is list the assembly annotated with the original C/C++ (or any high level compiled language) source line numbers, and hence source lines, but with high levels of optimisation this can still be impossible to match up precisely.

Comment: Was thinking to do it outside of the debugger, with parsing LL file and C Source, ideally re-using something .... how would you approach it? It is fine for me to do it for easy cases and allow non trivial to be false or non doable

Comment: https://github.com/avast/retdec

Comment: Is your question about how to match some LLVM IR to some existing C code you have, or is it about how to actually translate LLVM IR to C?